# Directives calling services directly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it a good practice to call services directly from a Angular JS Directive?

Here is an example: directive to take name as input and calls a service(connects to db) to get the HTML content and render it.

a service call is made inside the linkFn to get the HTML content

or

return {
   restrict:'EA',
   scope:{
     name:"=",
     getPartial : "&"
   },
   link:linkFn
  }

here getHTMLContent is implemented in the controller and calls the same service.

Comment: Remember that directives can have a controller. Try doing the same in controllers **instead** (services should not alter the element, but alter the scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Imagine if you put that directive in an "ng-repeat". You'd have way too many calls to the server. How you retrieve your model should be separate from the way you present the model.

Comment: Agreed , I was for using isolateScope and letting the controller do the service call.. rather than directly calling from directive's linkFn..